# How to share unfinished flutter app for review?

Tags: android, ios, flutter

So I'm learning to build my first app using Flutter. I can't find information around how I can share my prototype app while it is in development with friends and family. A lot of the information refers to how you can build and release apps on the market.

Currently I connect my own device to my IDE and I can launch it in developer mode on the phone. So if I wanted to show other people, I need to physically be in front of them. Or get a hold of their physical device and run debug mode on their device. This is very cumbersome and the turn around time is not immediate, which means friends and family loses interest in helping out very quickly.

This got me questioning how flutter developers in the real world work with clients? There has to be some way for you to send the app over to the client for review without having to actually release the app while it is in development? I mean in web development, you would just send them a staging link to review. What's the equivalent in flutter? This got me thinking - since flutter can also be developed for the web, would staging the app on the web be a good idea? Why or why not?

Comment: For iOS you can use TestFlight through AppStore Connect.  Your app does have to go through a basic review before you can make it available to external testers but it doesn't have to be fully functional since it is a test version

Answer (score 0):

1- You can build a release apk as output and share it manually.

https://flutter.dev/docs/deployment/android#build-an-apk

2- You can use internal app sharing in Google Play Developer Console.

[image]

3- For iOS you can use Test Flight

Answer (score 0):

You can create apk for your app if you want to share it with your friends

For apk (Android) run the command :

> flutter build apk --release

For ipa (iOS) run the command :

> flutter build ios --release

and after that go to this location:

> yourAppFolder/build/app/outputs/apk/release/app-release.apk

Then you can share this APK file through WhatsApp with your friends to test your app.

Comment: What about after making the iOS file? I'm not sure you can share that over WhatsApp or the like.